# How can I make this sidenav menu be fixed in computers, but collapsible in phones / tablets? See the gifs on the links down there 2 understand

Tags: html, css

I want THIS (I mean, the same menu system): https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5EtV.gif

I have THIS (I mean, the same menu system): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChI3e.gif

Here's the code I got:

```css
     body {
          margin: 0;
          font-family: Helvetica; 
        }
        .topnav {
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: rgb(159,44,40);
          height: 48px;
        }
        
        .topnav a {
          float: left;
          display: block;
          color: #f2f2f2;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 17px;
        }
        #myprofile {
            position: absolute;
            right: 12.5px;
        }
        #mailshortcut {
            position: absolute;
            right: 57.5px;
        }
        #notif {
            position: absolute;
            right: 102.5px;
            width: 69px;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        #calendarshortcut {
            position: absolute;
            right: 170px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        #search {
            position: absolute;
            right: 215.5px;
            width: 50px;
            padding: 14px 14px;
        }
        .topnav .unee {
          color: #CDB26E;
          text-transform: lowercase;
          font-weight: 800;
        }
        .active {
          font-weight: 800;
          text-transform: lowercase;
          position: absolute;
          left: 54px;
        }
        #univlogo {
          left: 25px;
          top: 4px;
          position: absolute;
        }
        .thelogo {
          position: absolute;
          right: 285px;
          top: 4px;
        }
        .badge {
         position: absolute;
         top:12px;
         right: 8px;
         padding: 5px 8px;
         border-radius: 50%;
         background-color: rgb(209,91,71);
         color: white;
         font-size: 10px;
         }
         #phonetablet {display: none;}
         @media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
            .column {
                 float: left;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 10px;
                height: 300px;
            }
            #phonetablet {
                display: block;
            }
            .topnav .responsive a .active {
              display: none;
            }
            #desktop {
              display: none;
            }
            #myprofile {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            width: 57px;
        }
        .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
        .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
        #univlogo {
          left: 40px;
          top: 4px;
          position: absolute;
        }
        .thelogo {
          position: absolute;
          right: 285px;
          top: 4px;

        }
        }
        #archive {
            background: #6e8cd0;
            color: white;
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        .sidenav {
        height: 100%;
        width: 200px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 48px;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #ddd;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding-top: 20px;
        border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
        }

        .sidenav a {
        padding: 6px 6px 6px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: rgb(88,88,88);
        display: block;
        font-size: 20px;
        border-top: #ccc solid 1px;
        }
        .first {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 200px;
        border: none;
        border-top: none;
        border-bottom: none;
        }
        .second {
        position: absolute;
        top: 37px;
        width: 200px;
        } 
        .secondhalf {
        position: absolute;
        top: 74px;
        width: 200px;
        }
        .third {
        position: absolute;
        top: 111px;
        width: 200px;
        }
        .fourth {
        position: absolute;
        top: 148px;
        width: 200px;
        }
        .fifth {
        position: absolute;
        top: 185px;
        width: 200px;
        }
        .sixth {
        position: absolute;
        top: 222px;
        width: 200px;
        border-bottom: #ccc solid 1px;
        }
        .seventh {
        position: absolute;
        top: 259px;
        width: 200px;
        border-bottom: #ccc solid 1px;
        }
        .sidenav a:hover {
        color: rgb(159,44,40);
        background: white;
        }
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <img id="univlogo" src="file:///Users/Ari/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/SIMON/SIMON%20TRABAJOS/ai%20doll%20face/Renault%202006/NewLogo.jpg" width="40" height="40">
        <img class="thelogo" id="desktop"src="file:///Users/Ari/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/SIMON/SIMON%20TRABAJOS/ai%20doll%20face/Renault%202006/thelogo.png" height="40" width="60">
        <img class="thelogo" id="phonetablet" src="file:///Users/Ari/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/SIMON/SIMON%20TRABAJOS/ai%20doll%20face/Renault%202006/shortened%20logo.png" height="40" width="60">
        <a href="file:///Users/Ari/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/SIMON/SIMON%20TRABAJOS/ai%20doll%20face/Renault%202006/Users/AriadnaMi.html" id="desktop" style="color: #CDB26E;" class="active">UNEE</a>
      </div>     

      <div class="sidenav">
        <!-- Add font awesome icons -->
        <a class="first" id="archive" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-archive"></i><strong> Histórico</strong></a>
          <a class="second" href="file:///Users/Ari/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/SIMON/SIMON%20TRABAJOS/ai%20doll%20face/Renault%202006/Users/AriadnaMi.html"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> <strong>Mi espacio</strong></a>
          <a class="secondhalf" href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> uneeChat</a>
          <a class="third" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i> uneeCloud</a>
          <a class="fourth" href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Asistencia</a>
          <a class="fifth" href="file:///Users/Ari/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/SIMON/SIMON%20TRABAJOS/ai%20doll%20face/Renault%202006/Users/Ariadna%20Mi%20Evaluation.html"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Evaluaciones</a>
          <a class="sixth" href="#"><i class="fa fa-film"></i> Cuatrimestres</a>
          <a class="seventh" href="#"><i style="font-style: italic !important;"class="fa fa-book"></i> Comisiones</a>
        </div>
</body>
```

"style.css" is the css code up here.

So, tell me what can I do to get the desired menu.

And I have tried once with a code made by myself, but I couldn't make it work.
Plus, I have searched for the solution in all forums on the internet and in coding websites, but I still cannot find the answer.

Please. Will you be able to solve my problem? Thank u in advance!

PS: The links in there are the pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use media queries for making your website content responsive for screen sizes , and for the collapse nav it's available in bootstrap if you like to build the code using it

Comment: I don't understand. Did you see the gifs in the links?

Comment: @SLMProductions yes i see , i mean that by using media querie you can change the width of each div according to the screen size so you can set them in the same line or horizontally

Comment: NO. I wanna make the menu collapsible in the phones and tablets, but fixed in computers. Not do what you are telling me to do.

Comment: You gave me a wonderful idea on how to continue with the website! thank u and sorry for not listening 2 u before!

Comment: you are welcomed